# I am trying to concat variable and string in stored procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to concatenate variable and string in mysql stored procedure for table name in select

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test`()
BEGIN
DECLARE demo1 VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE demo2 VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE concatenated VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE concatenated2 VARCHAR(100);
SET demo1 = ('tour_');
SET demo2 = ('companytb');
SET concatenated = CONCAT('tour_', 'companytb');
SET concatenated2 = CONCAT_WS(demo1, demo2);
SELECT DISTINCT company_name FROM concatenated;
END
```

I tried this, but I am getting this error:

> 01911:41:29 call test()
>
> Error Code: 1146. Table 'codimbii_live.concatenated' doesn't exist

Comment: You cannot use a variable as table name - the table name is a literal and won't be substituted. Use dynamic SQL (PREPARE statement).

Comment: Thank you @akina and SelVazi its working but returning Null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @akina in comments you will need to use some prepared statements, here is an exemple :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test`()
BEGIN
  DECLARE demo1 VARCHAR(100);
  DECLARE demo2 VARCHAR(100);
  DECLARE concatenated VARCHAR(100);
  DECLARE concatenated2 VARCHAR(100);
  SET demo1 = ('tour_');
  SET demo2 = ('companytb');
  SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT DISTINCT company_name FROM ', demo1, demo2);
  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;EXECUTE stmt;DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

Comment: Probably the table is empty ! what is the output of `SELECT DISTINCT company_name FROM tour_companytb` ? see it working here https://dbfiddle.uk/V88yGI0x

Comment: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0UZRV3Mq)   "domaindb" is what I tried.  The table has datas. actually its getting and displaying for 1 second and then showing null.

Comment: You got null because `SELECT DISTINCT db;` return `null` since the variable `db` is empty have a look here https://dbfiddle.uk/aXq9FhoM